# Rasterization of linear gradient

Tags: css, image, svg, webkit, browser

I am looking for some algorithms to rasterize the linear gradient definition, i.e. converting the linear gradient in to pixel colors in RGB color space. I have already seen the algorithm used by PS/PDF. But, I am more interested on web technologies.

Could someone please describe or provide some reference on how browsers(or webkit) typically do it while rendering SVG/CSS?

Comment: well the spec is a pretty good place to start - Section 4 of http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#linear-gradients